# what are the semantics of an iostream statement like myoutput << myinput.rdbuf() in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, iostream

take this code an example

```
std::ifstream myinput("myinput.txt");
std::ofstream myoutput("myoutout.txt");
myoutput << myinput.rdbuf();
```

1. what are the semantics of the operation?
2. C++ version is this specific overload of operator<< available in?
3. is there a more explicit way [by using a named function instead of operator] to achieve the same effect?
4. how can I tell how many bytes where copied in the operation?
5. can I limit the number of bytes copied?
6. can you outline how this specific overload of operator<< is implemented or point to an established implementation?

Comment: "4. how can I tell how many bytes where copied in the operation?" It seems like you've got a reasonably good idea of what's going on there in part 1 then, don't you?

Comment: well someone told me that it supposedly should copy the entire file. but I did not find any documentation on this, nor the specification of that particular operator<<, it semantics, its error conditions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It copies the entire input stream (the entire file) to the output stream.
2. It's always been available in C++. std::ifstream is defined in `<istream>` and std::ofstream is defined in `<ostream>`.
3. Nope, that's the only way.
4. Use myoutput.tellp().
5. You'll need to read from the stream manually in a loop using std::ifstream::read, copying data into a buffer and writing that data to the output stream using std::ofstream::write, until you've copied the amount you want.
6. If you have a C++ compiler installed, you can look at its implementation of it (most of the stream classes are templates, which means that their implementation must be in the header). For `std::basic_ios::rdbuf`, you can look in `<ios>`, and for `std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf*)`, you can look in `<ostream>`.

Comment: suppose the file is really large, does it continue reading from input file, or does it just copy the contents of the buffer?

Comment: @AviadRozenhek Same answer. All of the streams library has always been available in C++. In fact, I don't think it's ever even changed, except maybe in the very early stages of C++.